# How to print string on JTextField

Tags: java, jpanel, jtextfield

I want to show `String` `b`up on `TextField`. `String` `b` is a conversion of array of `stringChar`.

```
void setTextField(char s) {
     stringChar[index] = s;
     index++;
     String b = new String(string);
     System.out.println(b);
     TextField.setText(b);
}
```

If I execute the code, then the String is not displayed in the textfield.

Comment: Can you see `b` in console ? What is the value of `string` ?

Comment: new String(string), what is the string variable? Didn't see your comment TAsk***

Comment: You're probably blocking the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Are you sure that TextField is the correct reference that you add at the panel that you want to show, update your question with all code that you are using

Comment: Daniel kim, if we helped accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

You said:  I want to show string b up on TextField. string b is a converion of array of stringChar.

But in the code you wrote: `String b = new String(string);`

Instead of that is should be: `String b = new String(stringChar);`

Also, you should repaint the textfield: `TextField.repaint();`

Answer (score -2):

> Blockquote
>   JTextArea.setText(string);
>   JTextArea.append(string);

java doc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html

Comment: This does not make any sense. For what we know he could have string as a global variable. Secondly your code is not in code tags, well now it is. third it should be String not string the first 2 times, because String is a class, but string is a variable.

Comment: No need to change the method of doing what he want's to do. he simply mistyped a variable..